# Upload new project into github repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a android project, I am working on and it, currently does not reside on a source control of any type.

I have created my own github account and created a repository there and now i want to commit and push my android project into that repo.

how do i do that?

I have tried doinga  git checkout and it doesnt work and says that the project is not a git repo.

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a local git repository you can sync first.
Enter your base source folder and type:

```
git init
```

This initializes a new git repository. Then you need to commit your code.

```
git add *
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Now you can sync it. For this you have to add a remote repository to your local repository.
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Once you have done that, you can push your local files with:

```
git push origin master
```

Where origin is the name of the remote repository and master the name of the branch.

Ps.: You'll also have to sync the SSH keys for this to work.
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Edit: If you are not sure what that means, head directly to the Github bootcamp:
https://help.github.com/categories/54/articles

Answer (score 1):

You must init your folder

```
git init
```